# How to add a list of structures to an existing structure

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list

I am designing a basic XML parser in **C** and am trying to figure out a way to add nodes (both child and parents). So my idea as of now is to have one datatype,node, which looks like this

```
struct node{
    char* name;
    char* value;
    struct node* parent; // if is a child set this to the parent node
    //how to make a list of child nodes
    int numChildren;
    struct node* nextParent;// allow me to iterate through top level parent level nodes
};
```

So if a node is a parent it will have its Parent pointer set to NULL. 
I know how to add nodes to my linked list, but I don't get how to add child nodes to a "node list". So any ideas on how I would do that

Answer (score 2):

One common way to create a tree structure is the following:

```
struct node {
    //additional values...

    struct node *parent; //optional
    struct node *firstChild;
    struct node *nextSibling;
};
```

Essentially, each node contains a linked list of its children. The first child is `theNode->firstChild`, the second child is `theNode->firstChild->nextSibling`, and so on, until `nextSibling==NULL` for the last child.

Leaf nodes will have `firstChild==NULL`, and the root node has `parent==NULL`.

Adding a child to a node will then be done in the same manner as adding a node to a linked list. For example, to add a child in front of the other children:

```
allocate newNode and initialize its fields.
newNode->parent = parentNode;
newNode->nextSibling = parentNode->firstChild;
parentNode->firstChild = newNode;
```

Comment: interjay, could you give me a small example of adding children? The implementation is the part I am having trouble with.

Comment: @lodkkx: I just added an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define MAXCHILD N
struct node{
    char* name;
    char* value;
    struct node* parent; 
    //int numChildren; if fixed number of children for each node then use macro
    struct node* nextParent[MAXCHILD];
};
```

Or,

try using `malloc()` and make `nextParent` as `struct node** nextParent` pointer to pointer.Allocate according to number of each node's children. Like this below.

`struct node *treenode;

treenode = malloc(sizeof(*treenode));

treenode -> numChildren = 2; // It must be initialized with value otherwise may

                      // take any garbage value.

treenode -> nextParent = malloc((treenode -> numChildren) * sizeof(struct node*));`

But `numChildren` should be initialized

Comment: Your second option is what I need help implementing, could you show me an example?